# cast exception on an eventclick handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

Learning ASP. got this problem, made 9 imagebuttons and want to handle them with the same handler:

```
    protected void jugar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        String turno = (string)Session["Turno"];
        ImageButton boton = (ImageButton)sender;
        if (turno == "1")
        {
            boton.ImageUrl = "C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\Tic-tac-toe-cross.png";
            Session["Turno"] = 2;
        }
        else if (turno == "2")
        {
            boton.ImageUrl = "C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\Tic-tac-toe-nought-e1461667111145.png";
            Session["Turno"] = 1;
        }
    }
```

Its throwing a cast exception,

Any idea on whats wrong??

these are the buttons that refer to this handler:

```
    <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <asp:TableRow runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Style="border-bottom: solid 2px red; border-right: solid 2px red">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn00" runat="server" class="imagen" ImageUrl="C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\White_square.jpg" OnClick="jugar_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" style="border-left:solid 2px red;border-bottom:solid 2px red;border-right:solid 2px red">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn01" runat="server" class="imagen" ImageUrl="C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\White_square.jpg" OnClick="jugar_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" style="border-left:solid 2px red;border-bottom:solid 2px red">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn02" runat="server" class="imagen" ImageUrl="C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\White_square.jpg" OnClick="jugar_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" style="border-top:solid 2px red;border-bottom:solid 2px red;border-right:solid 2px red">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn10" runat="server" class="imagen" ImageUrl="C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\White_square.jpg" OnClick="jugar_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" style="border-top:solid 2px red;border-bottom:solid 2px red;border-left:solid 2px red;border-right:solid 2px red">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn11" runat="server" class="imagen" ImageUrl="C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\White_square.jpg" OnClick="jugar_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" style="border-top:solid 2px red;border-bottom:solid 2px red;border-left:solid 2px red">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn12" runat="server" class="imagen" ImageUrl="C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\White_square.jpg" OnClick="jugar_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" style="border-top:solid 2px red;border-right:solid 2px red">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn20" runat="server" class="imagen" ImageUrl="C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\White_square.jpg" OnClick="jugar_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" style="border-top:solid 2px red;border-left:solid 2px red;border-right:solid 2px red">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn21" runat="server" class="imagen" ImageUrl="C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\White_square.jpg" OnClick="jugar_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" style="border-top:solid 2px red;border-left:solid 2px red">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btn22" runat="server" class="imagen" ImageUrl="C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\White_square.jpg" OnClick="jugar_Click"></asp:ImageButton>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
```

sorry for lack of info, im a newbie

Comment: You have something initiating the click event that is not an ImageButton

Comment: Or something in the session that isn't a string. The lack of a stack trace or [mcve] makes it hard to know.

Comment: He is storing an integer value in his `Session["Turno"]` and seems to needlessly be casting it to a string.  But that shouldn't cause a cast exception because string and integer have an implicit conversion? IIRC.

Comment: Run it under your debugger, which line is throwing the cast exception exactly?

Comment: @Ratatoskr: No, there's no implicit conversion from between `int` and `string`, and even if there were, that's not used for an unboxing conversion. (For example, if you have `object x = 10; byte b = (byte) x;` that will still throw.)

Comment: I think I might have my verbiage wrong.  Shouldn't there be an implicit conversion for int and string if you're able to do `"This is a string - " + 0 + " - with an integer"`?  I think I'm just having a brain fart today since I don't have VS handy :\.  I think the compiler actually boxes the int in this case. I think I'm going to get some coffee since I keep getting schooled this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this line throwing exception `ImageButton boton = (ImageButton)sender;` per your posted code ... if yes then the `sender` is definitely not a `ImageButton` rather some other control type

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void jugar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) {

 if (sender is ImageButton) {

  var turNo = Session["Turno"];

  var buttonSender = (ImageButton)sender;

  switch (turNo) {
   case 1:
    buttonSender.ImageUrl = "C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\Tic-tac-toe-cross.png";
    Session["Turno"] = 2;
    break;
   case 2:
    buttonSender.ImageUrl = "C:\Users\Epyros\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EnTA TE TI\EnTA TE TI\Imagenes\Tic-tac-toe-nought-e1461667111145.png";
    Session["Turno"] = 1;
    break;
   default:
    // Logic for turNo != 1 or 2
    break;
  }
 }
 else
 {
     // sender is not the expected type (ImageButton)
     Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Sender is an unexpected type. Expected: (ImageButton), got ({0}).", sender.GetType().Name),"WARN");
 }
}
```

This code should prevent you from running into cast exceptions, as well as inform you of the type of the sender that is the culprit.

Comment: What if `sender` is not an ImageButton? The cast exceptions will turn into null ref exceptions with this code.

Comment: And instead, the OP could get a `NullReferenceException` without the information of the *actual* type, and delayed in execution time from when the world wasn't as expected. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions/

Comment: If sender is not an ImageButton, then the condition on the if will be false, and not execute the code block within.

Comment: So cast after the `is`. Or use C# 7's pattern matching. There's no reason to use `as` unless you're really expecting it to be "not the right type" in a *non-error* situation. But I strongly suspect that it really, really *should* always be an `ImageButton`, and if it's not, that indicates a bug - so you're really just disguising the bug, even if now doesn't throw an exception. (I suspect that the actual problem is the session part.)

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess I got tunneled into the is/as when i could have just cast it instead.  Updated my answer.

Comment: It's still missing the point that just avoiding an exception isn't enough to make the code bug-free - and often avoiding the exception instead of investigating it makes it harder to find the actual problem.

Comment: Another fair point.  I added an else so that you could trace when an unexpected type was encountered, which should help identify what type is actually being passed as the sender in cases where he could be getting the exception.